# Data Migration with Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I am trying to migrate the weird and complex data from excelsheet to oracle 10g xe database with validation.So, i read at somewhere that it is too easy with Oracle ADF Desktop Integration.

Can anyone guide me for that? 
==Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create simple GUI for data insertion using ADF. But in fact you might even not need any user interface to do your job (unless it is for a customer).

Maybe the most important part is actually the ADF Business Layer (business components) and the ability to use Java in it.
Using Java and the ApachePOY library, you can create a simple Excel parser - I have written more about it here: http://blog.dreamix.eu/java/read-excel-files-with-java.

Then you can use the business components to make the data insertion and validation.

Have fun and if you need more help you can contact me through the blogpost.